# Custom services returns null

Tags: services, 8

I have extended [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module and created a custom web service to get and post data.
The problem is on the first rest call I get proper response but on the next response I receive "null" where as in my local environment the code works fine.

here is the code:

```
    $api = array(
    'pe_quiz_api' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        'retrieve' => array(
          'help' => 'Retrieve a quiz',
          'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'includes/pe_quiz_api.services'),
          'callback' => '_pe_quiz_api_resource_retrieve',
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'qid',
              'optional' => FALSE,
              'source' => array('path' => 0),
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => 'The qid of the quiz to retrieve.',
            ),
          ),
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        ),
        'create' => array(
          'help' => 'Create a quiz submission',
          'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'includes/pe_quiz_api.services'),
          'callback' => '_pe_quiz_api_resource_create',
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'submit_data',
              'optional' => FALSE,
              'source' => 'data',
              'description' => 'quiz submission entry',
              'type' => 'array',
            ),
          ),
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $api;
```

Comment: my server is nginx and i have memcache enabled

Comment: I faced a similar issue recently with a client, I believe it was due to a server side cache like varnish or memcache. Configure anything like that to ignore all requests to your API, e.g. `?q=my-endpoint/*`

Comment: what is the best possible solution to this? i cant disable memcache in the production server, is there any workaround for the same? @tyler.frankenstein

Comment: the native services works fine, its just my custom extended services code which returns null

Comment: this issue has been fixed.

Comment: 'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'includes/pe_quiz_api.services')

the above line should have 'module' name similar to the custom module name
in my case 
'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'pe_quiz_api', 'name' => 'includes/pe_quiz_api.services')

Comment: @ChintanSureliya Don't feel hesitate to answer your own question. Comment is not a good place to post code snippet.